# Laravel auth emails localisation

Tags: laravel

Laravel uses `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword` class to send password reset email. The message is written in english. How do I translate it into another language. Publishing vendor files doesn't copy this class. I can't edit it since it is in vendor files and is not in the vcs repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email notification is sent from `CanResetPassword` trait, you need to override the method responsible for this and provide your own notification class.

```
User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new MyResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
    // ...
}
```

And create the notification:

```
MyResetPasswordNotification extends Notification
{
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line(trans('reset_password.first_line'))
            ->action(trans('reset_password.action', ['route' => route('password.reset', $this->token)))
            ->line(trans('reset_password.last_line');
    }
}
```

Now you just need to provide the translations.